# Rails 3: Make token inputs sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using token inputs in a text field and would like to also make these tokens sortable (JQuery UI). I am using Ryan Bates screencast to get started however I am unsure how to apply [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) to my code. Here is what I have...

```
<fieldset id="presenters">
  <p>
    <%= event_form.label :presenter_tokens, "Presenters" %>
    <%= event_form.text_field :presenter_tokens, "data-pre" => @event.presenter_tokens_tokeninput.to_json  %>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the HTML I get...

```
<fieldset id="presenters">
<p>
<label for="event_presenter_tokens">Presenters</label>
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<li class="token-input-token-facebook">
<p>Mark</p>
<span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">×</span>
</li>
<li class="token-input-token-facebook">
<p>Laurie</p>
<span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">×</span>
</li>
<li class="token-input-input-token-facebook">
</ul>
<input data-pre="[{"id":131,"name":"Mark"},{"id":1311,"name":"Laurie"}]" id="event_presenter_tokens" name="event[presenter_tokens]" size="30" type="text" value="131,1311" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by using https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list